# Codeigniter Send Data/Parameter to PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

I'am familiar with mysql server and now try to learn postgresql.

Before, I save/update data from CI using mssql store procedure
sample:

**my controller**

```
$data = array(
  'name' => $_POST['name'],
);
$insert = $this->db->save($data);
```

**my model**

```
public function save($data){
        $sp = "insert ?";
        $result = $this->db->query($sp,$data);
        return $this->db->affected_rows();
    }
```

I'am try to implement that code to call postgresql function but it give me error like this

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "insert" LINE 1: insert E'name'

this is my postgresql function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert(name varchar(50)) RETURNS refcursor AS $$
DECLARE 
    nama varchar(50);
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dt_anggota VALUES(nama);
END;
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

Whats wrong with my code or my function?

Thank You

Comment: can't you just go like this:-`public function save($data){
 $result = $this->db->insert('provide table name here',$data);
 return $this->db->affected_rows();
}`

Comment: @AlivetoDie i need to send param to store procedure/function because its not just save name and that operation i put at function

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution
my code is like this

```
$sp = "select 'function_name' (?)";
$result = $this->db->query($sp,$data);
return $this->db->affected_rows();
```